# iTextSharp - PdfSmartCopy - How do I create internal anchor references across merged documents?

Tags: merge, itext, anchor

I am merging two documents using PdfSmartCopy and GetImportedPage.  The first document contains an anchor reference to an anchor name in the second document.

When the documents are merged the anchor reference does not work. Here is the demonstration code, compiled against iTextSharp 5.4.5.0

In the sample code, "Go To Anchor 2" does not work in the merged file (file3.pdf).

Has anyone solved this one or can see why?

```
        using (var fs1 = new FileStream("c:/test/file1.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs1);
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page 1"));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Go To Anchor 1") { Reference = "#AnchorReference1" });
                doc.Add(new Paragraph(""));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Go To Anchor 2") { Reference = "#AnchorReference2" });
                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page 2"));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Anchor 1") { Name = "AnchorReference1" });
                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var fs2 = new FileStream("c:/test/file2.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs2);
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page 3"));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Anchor 2") { Name = "AnchorReference2" });
                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var ms3 = new FileStream("c:/test/file3.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                var copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, ms3);
                doc.Open();
                var pdfReader1 = new PdfReader("c:/test/file1.pdf");
                var pdfReader2 = new PdfReader("c:/test/file2.pdf");
                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader1, 1));
                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader1, 2));
                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader2, 1));
                doc.Close();
            }
        }
```

---

Here is an updated example of the same problem but using the code from ConcatenateNamedDestinations example in chapter 7 of the 'iText in action' second edition.

```
        using (var fs1 = new FileStream("c:/test/file1.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs1);
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page 1"));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Go To Anchor 1") { Reference = "#AnchorReference1" });
                doc.Add(new Paragraph(""));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Go To Anchor 2") { Reference = "#AnchorReference2" });
                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page 2"));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Anchor 1") { Name = "AnchorReference1" });
                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var fs2 = new FileStream("c:/test/file2.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs2);
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page 3"));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Anchor 2") { Name = "AnchorReference2" });
                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        PdfReader[] readers = { new PdfReader("c:/test/file1.pdf"), new PdfReader("c:/test/file2.pdf") };

        using (var ms = new FileStream("c:/test/file3.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var document = new  Document())
            {
                using (var copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms))
                {
                    document.Open();
                    int n;
                    for (int i = 0; i < readers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        readers[i].ConsolidateNamedDestinations();
                        n = readers[i].NumberOfPages;
                        for (int page = 0; page < n; )
                        {
                            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(readers[i], ++page));
                        }
                    }
                    // Add named destination  
                    copy.AddNamedDestinations(
                        // from the second document
                      SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(readers[1], false),
                        // using the page count of the first document as offset
                      readers[0].NumberOfPages
                    );
                }
            }

            // Create a reader
            var reader = new PdfReader("c:/test/file3.pdf");
            // Convert the remote destinations into local destinations
            reader.MakeRemoteNamedDestinationsLocal();
            using (var ms2 = new FileStream("c:/test/file4.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                // Create a new PDF containing the local destinations
                using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms2))
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

---

Solved:

```
        using (var fs1 = new FileStream("c:/test/file1.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs1);
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page 1"));
                var anchor1Chunk = new Chunk("Click for Anchor 1");
                var anchor2Chunk = new Chunk("Click for Anchor 2");
                anchor1Chunk.SetAction(PdfAction.GotoLocalPage("AnchorReference1", false));
                anchor2Chunk.SetAction(PdfAction.GotoLocalPage("AnchorReference2", false));
                doc.Add(new Paragraph(anchor1Chunk));
                doc.Add(new Paragraph(anchor2Chunk));
                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page 2"));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Anchor 1") { Name = "AnchorReference1" });
                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var fs2 = new FileStream("c:/test/file2.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs2);
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page 3"));
                doc.Add(new Anchor("Anchor 2") { Name = "AnchorReference2" });
                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        PdfReader[] readers = { new PdfReader("c:/test/file1.pdf"), new PdfReader("c:/test/file2.pdf") };

        using (var ms = new FileStream("c:/test/file3.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var document = new  Document())
            {
                using (var copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms))
                {
                    document.Open();
                    int n;
                    for (int i = 0; i < readers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        readers[i].ConsolidateNamedDestinations();
                        n = readers[i].NumberOfPages;
                        for (int page = 0; page < n; )
                        {
                            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(readers[i], ++page));
                        }
                    }
                    // Add named destination  
                    copy.AddNamedDestinations(
                        // from the second document
                      SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(readers[1], false),
                        // using the page count of the first document as offset
                      readers[0].NumberOfPages
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a link from document A to document B using a named destination, and if you merge document A with document B resulting in a document C, it should be obvious that the links that were in document A still refer to document B, and not to document C.

If you want them to refer to document C, you need to consolidate the named destinations and make the remote links local as is documented in chapter 7 of my book. See the ConcatenateNamedDestinations example: [Java version](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=133) / [C# version](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter07/ConcatenateNamedDestinations.cs).

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  I have used the code in the example but still no success.  I have updated the issue to include the new code example.

Comment: Maybe the links aren't using named destinations. Do you have any idea what type of  action is used for link annotations?

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  I am using named destinations as shown in the example code: doc.Add(new Anchor("Anchor 2") { Name = "AnchorReference2" });

Comment: Solved - thanks.  I used Chunk.SetAction(PdfAction.GotoLocalPage("AnchorReference1", false)) instead of new Anchor("Anchor Reference 1") { Destination = "#AnchorReference1" } plus the code from your example.  Solved.